# Php loop skipping some lines from csv file

Tags: php, csv

I am not a programmer nor doing the script for someone else. It is just for my personal use. I got help creating the below code. I would appreciate if you can help me fix a bug in below code.

The code below pulls coins list from the all.csv file. Every coin is in its separate line. Currently there are 197 coins in the all.csv file (197) total lines.

The pulled coins are inserted in to script that is used to pull data from tradingview widget ( https://www.tradingview.com/widget/ticker/)

With the current code below the script works but:
It skips coins(lines) 34 to 55 (including 34 and 55). 
It skips coins between 166-176 (including 166 th and 176th coin). 
Also it is not showing the coins after 188 (including 188).

Sample lines are as below: (there are no spaces between them.) I couldnt figure our to the new lines in stackoverflow. In the code if I change "delta" to 15 it skips the lines 31-60

BITTREX:NAVBTC

BITTREX:WAVESBTC

BITTREX:ETCBTC

BITTREX:SALTBTC

BITTREX:ARDRBTC

```
<?php
$tickers = array();
$f = fopen("all.csv", "r");
while (($line = fgetcsv($f)) !== false) {
 $lines = explode("\r", $line[0]);
  foreach ($lines as $cell) { 
  $tickers[] = $cell;
  }
}
fclose($f);
?>
<?php
$start = 0;
$delta = 11;
for($i = 0; $i <= (int)(count($tickers)/$delta); $i += 1) {
$t = array_slice($tickers, $start, $delta);
$out = implode('"}, {"description": "","proName": "', $t);
echo '<script src="https://s3.tradingview.com/external-embedding/embed-widget-tickers.js">{
"symbols": [{"description": "","proName": "'.$out.'"}],
    "locale": "en"
}</script>';
$start += $delta;
}
?>
```

Comment: Could you include some lines which do work and some which don't in your question.

Comment: thanks for reply. I have updated the original post.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you appear to be separating your file into lines using the carriage return character, "\r".  While this might work if the file was generated in Windows, it won't work if all or some of it came from Linux or another OS which uses "\n" only instead of "\r\n" at line endings.

Secondly, you can save yourself some pain and use the file() function (http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) which does all the file opening and line splitting for you, and puts the results neatly into an array, e.g.:

```
$lines = file("all.csv");
foreach ($lines as $cell) {
    // etc...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have changed it to \n, and also before changing to \n saved it in windows file format. But it didn't change anything.

Comment: This won't be very helpful but I can't reproduce your bug, given the code and some dummy data (which may or may not be similarly formatted) - it's not skipping any lines for me!  I would have to see your exact input to be able to figure out what's going on.

The only other suggestion I have for you is to use the constant PHP_EOL instead of a literal "\r" (MacOS) or "\n" (Linux) or "\r\n" (Windows). This will ensure you are handling line endings correctly, regardless of your platform.

Also, please use indentation in your code - it makes it a lot easier to read!